# Can NOT Execute Java Command From External Java Folder

Tags: java, swing, bash

I have a folder which contains external JAVA so client does NOT have to install java on her/his computer my application will run on this my java folder.

This application is swing app and it will be cross platform.

Here is my code:

```
                            // this is my external java folder and in folder it is "java.exe"
Process process = run.exec("./java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -jar " + "./app/app-1.1.jar " + commandSuffix);
```

It says file not found exception i changed to "java.exe" but also it does NOT work i need to run this command in this JAVA code so it will be platform independent.

When i changed to code like this: `run.exec("java -jar " + "./app/app-1.1.jar " + commandSuffix);` it works because system calls real java path but i need to run previous code from my java folder so client does NOT have to install java.

Comment: are you actually trying to execute another java-binary within your running java-app???

Comment: yes i'm trying to do execute app from external different java folder

Comment: why would you want to run 2 JVMs at the same time?

Comment: no that is not what i want.In windows we have created bat file which contains this command : "./java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -jar " + "./app/app-1.1.jar " + commandSuffix. And we successfully executed it and it worked so i need to do this thing here in java.

Comment: that would run two java virtual machines at the same time, i think you need to re-evaluate your strategy and maybe examine the technology quite a bit, apparenty you got confused at some point.

Comment: The code you are trying to run is also in Java. So this one won't run if your client doesn't have Java. Use .bat file for Windows and .sh file for Unix

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat file and place in this my java folder

so your folder should contain this

```
 java   -> folder containing jdk1.7.0_67
 app    -> folder containing app-1.1.jar
 run.bat
```

Contains of run.bat file

```
  java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -jar app/app-1.1.jar commandSuffix
```

similarly create .sh file for unix